# Component Text Content Update On Layout

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm using Typescript and I've got this (functional) React Native Component:

```js
export default function BasicView(props: BasicViewProps): ReactElement {
  const wRef = useRef<number>(0);

  function onLayout(event: LayoutChangeEvent) {
    const {width} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    wRef.current = width;
    console.log('wRef: ' + wRef.current);
  }

  return (
    <View
      onLayout={onLayout}
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "darkgray",
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>{wRef.current}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Everything seems to be working with my `onLayout` code. My problem is that the content in the `<Text/>` component (which is intended to be printing out `wRef.current`) is not updating; currently `0` is printed and never changes. I think I partially understand *why* it's not updating, but my question is *how* do I get it to update with the value of `wRef.current`?

For what it's worth, I don't plan on this component updating frequently, but I just need a single update to get the initial value of the View's layout width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this and it seems to be working

```
export default function App() {
  const wRef = React.useRef(0);
const [width, setwidth] = React.useState("")
  function onLayout(event: LayoutChangeEvent) {
    const {width} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    wRef.current = width;
    setwidth(width)
    console.log('wRef: ' + wRef.current);
  }

  return (
    <View
      onLayout={onLayout}
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "darkgray",
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>{width}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

and about your issue, I have never tried printing a ref value but your problem looks like about state which is taking it's initial value, I have solved this type of issue with updating extra useState just to update state.

Comment: Hey Bhrugu, thanks for the answer. I'll give this a shot. I do have a dumb question about functional component state in React Native. Is state shared between all instances of a component? Or does each instance of a component have its own state? So if I have the component rendered multiple times and at different sizes on the same screen, will they each have a different `width` value in their state?

Comment: I played around with this, and was able to confirm that the state is specific to an instance. :) For some reason, I was previously under the impression that state was statically shared between all instances of a component.

Comment: Hello @AustinBrown if I have understand you question correctly the short answer is yes. the thing is if you want height or width of a component from onLayout param you have to wait for it to render. for example if you need height of a View which has a Flatlist and indefinite height in style parameter then it will depends on flatlist's render item and you have to let it render before calling for height. Hope I have understood your question right. If you have any or any other have good knowledge in this area please correct me.